# Ionic ion-refresher attr on-pulling can not work

Tags: ionic-framework

I want the search form hide on init, scroll down to show. But when I used on-pulling on ion-refresher,it didn't work.

code:

`<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="doRefresh()" on-pulling="showSearch()"></ion-refresher>`

Comment: Could you please provide some additional details such as your controller and any relevant services/factories/etc?

Comment: myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){ $scope.showSearch = function(){...}})              Did you use on-pulling before?

Answer (score 0):

Check this may help you...

```
<ion-refresher
    pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
    on-refresh="loadTransactionList()"
    refreshing-text="Refreshing!">
</ion-refresher>
```

The controller method is:

```
$scope.loadTransactionList = function(){
    console.log("Refresh called");
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
}
```

Comment: I do not want to do refresh,I just want to do sth.(show the search item) when I start to pull down on the refresher.